# Sql server, insert data into two tables, populate one before the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, bulkinsert

My first post here as I am starting in a new job where my old sql skills already are on the test - I am not advanced user from before either.
I believe there might be some answers here already that might be answering my question, but I am still a bit unfamiliar - both with the forum and more advanced sql syntaxes. Some answers are pretty old as well. 
And - please excuse me for any grammatical errors.

Anyways, if anyone might be able to help.

I will be receive huge lists (.csv or similar) with data input. 
The datalists will contain fields for type customerdata (name, address etc) and fields for type real estate/property data (street address, buildingIDs etc).

The customerdata and propertydata needs to be put into two separate tables.

My problem is like this:
- The two tables are depended on eachother as in the propertydata table needs to be populated with data first, which will generate a unique GUID - which again will be used when populating the customerdata table - connecting the customer to the correct property/real estate.

The first thing that came to mind is to populate all data into a temporary table.

But I am not quite sure how to loop through each row so I ensure that propertytable is populated first, then the customertable using the GUID.

1. Get data that involves propertydata and populate the property table
2. Get the unique GUID generated in property table
3. Get data that involves customerdata and populate the customer table - with correct GUID
4. Loop through rest of the set until there are no more rows with data.

I have seen some things like transactions, cursors, output etc that seems to be within my scope, but not sure which would be best way to solve my challenge? Am I near something when thinking like that?

**EDIT:**
These are example fields that will come as one row in .xlsx/.csv format.
Number of rows in such list will vary from time to time.

> 1. Property ID
> 2. Property address
> 3. Property building ID (only one)
> 4. Property established date
> 5. ...Misc other property related fields
> 6. Customer ID
> 7. Customer Name
> 8. Customer Address
> 9. Postal code
> 10. ...Misc other customer related fields

Fields 1 through 5 will need to populate a property table first. When each row in property table is populated it will generate unique GUID.
Then fields 6 through 10 will be used to populate a customer table, but also need to be populated with the corresponding unique GUID created above in the property table.

Property table:

> 1. Property ID
> 2. Property address
> 3. Property building ID (only one)
> 4. Property established date
> 5. ...Misc other property related fields
> 6. **UNIQUE PROPERTY GUID** (created when populating each new row in table)

Customer table:

> 7. **UNIQUE PROPERTY GUID**
> 8. Customer ID
> 9. Customer Name
> 10. Customer Address
> 11. Postal code
> 12. ...Misc other customer related fields

Comment: can you script it using something like powershell? Parse the csv, loop: add to propertydata table, get guid, add to customerdata table, repeat...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  So would an appropriate database tag.

Comment: @codebrane No, very likely not due to restriction policies. I am not that familiar with powershell either,

Comment: @GordonLinoff I gave some more input above, don't know if that makes more sense?

Comment: How are properties related to customers in the ".csv" like files? I don't see a relating field.

Comment: @FarhadRahmanifard That is where the UNIQUE GUID created when property table is populated comes into use. I guess I could do this in 2 separate operations, but would prefer to do it in one :)

Comment: Just to confirm: Relationship between property and customer is 1 to 1 i.e. you simply want to split 1 csv row into two halfs (property and customer)?

Comment: I have got how they relate to each other in the database, but how you link that UNIQUE GUID to a customer record?

Comment: @Alex Yes, that is pretty much it!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a staging table.

1. Load all data into a staging / temporary table and assign GUID numbers to each row.
2. Copy property details from staging table to property table taking GUID from the staging table
3. Copy customer details from staging table to customer table taking GUID from the staging table.
4. Delete data in staging table.

A quick example:

```
INSERT INTO PropertyDetails( GUID, PropertyID, PropertyAddress, ... )
SELECT GUID, PropertyID, PropertyAddress, ...
FROM StagingTable

INSERT INTO CustomertDetails( GUID, CustomerID, CustomerName, ... )
SELECT GUID, PropertyID, PropertyAddress, ...
FROM StagingTable
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking along these lines - but was not sure if this is the "easiest" way to accomplish what I need. I will try it out and see if this does the trick :)

Comment: @gorrhyse, this is a standard approach in data loading when you need to apply some form of data transformation. It is also more reliable as the process is split into independent stages, where validation can be applied if needed.